# how to customize wordpress registration form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload file during registration in wordpress.It is not showing `$_FILES` so i want to add `enctype = multipart/form-data` in wordpress default registration form.How can i add it to registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this inside your custom form area called by `register_form` hook

```
<script>
   jQuery('form#registerform').attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
</script>
```